# magnetometer conversion factor

Tags: android, android-sensors, magnetometer

I am working on sensor **HAL** in Android ICS,specifically Magnetometer.

I am referring to a code where a `(+/-)CONVERT_M` is multiplied to all the axis.
Where `CONVERT_M = (1.0f/16.0f)`
Based on what the figure `16.0f` is arrived on?

My understanding was , if the magnetometer driver returns the value in `Gauss` to convert it to `Tesla` it has to be multiplied by `(1.0f/10000.f)`.
Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding was , if the magnetometer driver returns the value in Gauss to convert it to Tesla it has to be multiplied by (1.0f/10000.f).

It is a factor of 10000

> => 1 Gs = 10<sup>-4</sup> T

Comment: I believe you mean multiply by "(1.0f/10000.f)".